# Pandas to_sql with transactions

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, postgresql, transactions

I'm trying to use pandas to_sql with several transactions so that if any of to_sql calls fails then all will be rollbacked. My test code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

data = {'col1': ['val1', 'val2'],
        'col2': ['val3', 'val4']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1', 'col2'])
engine_pg = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/postgres')
engine_ora = sqlalchemy.create_engine('oracle://user:pass@localhost:1521/orcl', max_identifier_length=128)
conn_pg = engine_pg.connect()
conn_ora = engine_ora.connect()
trans_pg = conn_pg.begin()
trans_ora = conn_ora.begin()
try:
    df.to_sql('table', conn_pg, schema='public', if_exists='replace', index=False) 
    df.to_sql('table', conn_ora, schema='user', if_exists='replace', index=False) #1
    trans_pg.commit() #2
    trans_ora.commit()
except Exception:
    trans_pg.rollback()
    trans_ora.rollback()
```

This seems to work fine with Postgres but not with Oracle. Table in Postgres is created after commit at #2 as expected but Oracle table is created already at #1.

1. Why does Oracle create table before transaction is committed? As far as I know there is no autocommit to be set on the server side.
2. Is this the right way to use transactions with pandas to_sql? Probably not, since if I want 2 transactions on the same connection it would not work since to_sql takes connection as parameter, not transaction.

Comment: Have you correctly configured tnsnames.ora? cause for oracle connection you need to configure this file

Comment: I have no experience with Oracle, but some googling seems to indicate that Oracle just doesn't support transactional DDL, or at least not out-of-the-box. Your usage of to_sql is fine, I think it'll do what you're expecting (but if there's something unexpected occurring, please do detail it).

Comment: Thank you @AdamKG! You are right, Oracle does not support transactional DDL. I'm new with Oracle and did not expect this. I changed in my test code if_exists='append' and confirmed that no lines were added if there is exception before the commits.

Comment: How would you do it if you need 2 transactions on the SAME database? Open 2 connections with 1 transaction each?

Comment: Yes. For PG at least, one connection has at most one active transaction at a time; I imagine other DBs are similar, not sure how else it could be handled.